# Pass parameter from Winform to UserControl

Tags: forms, user-controls, parameter-passing

I have a UserControl in a Winform and I would like to pass a parameter, here's what I'm doing:

In the User Control:

```
   public List<ushort[]> pixels16 { get; set;}
```

In the Form:

```
VolumeView controlv = new VolumeView(); //VolumeView is the UserControl
controlv.pixels16 = pixels16_img; //pixels16 is the variable in the Form that I need to use in the UserControl
```

It works, however, when I run a function in the UserControl, then the value is set to null:

```
 public void CreateVolume()
        {
            pixels16 is null!
}
```

what I'm doing wrong? I basically need to use a Form variable in a function within the UserControl..

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried passing the object as a parameter in the UserControl's constructor?